# Laplace Transforms with Non-repeated Irreducible quadratic factors

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform, inverse-laplace

I'm solving the following differential equation with a Laplace Transform:

$$x″+ 9x = \cos(t) + \delta(t-\pi)$$

The initial conditions are that x(0) and x'(0) are equal to 0.

After after the transform, we obtain:

$$F(S) = \frac{S}{(S^2+9)[(S^2+1)+9]} + \frac{e^{-\pi\cdot t}}{S^2+9}$$

The problem is that there are two unique irreducible quadratic factors in the denominator of that first term: therefore I cannot seem to find a way to simplify this to find equivalent components which would make the inverse transform easier. How do I find the inverse of that first term?

$$\frac{S}{(S^2+9)[(S^2+1)+9]}$$

The answer includes simple cos(t) and cos(3t) terms with coefficients of $\frac{1}{8}$ and $\frac{-1}{8}$ respectively. What is the process of going from this complex laplace transform to something so simple?

Comment: You can still factor into linear factors with complex roots. Alternatively, you can find a partial fraction decomposition of the form $(AS + B)/(S^2 + 9) + (CS + D)/(S^2 + 1)$ for some $A,B,C,D$ real and use facts about Laplace transforms of $\sin$ and $\cos$

Comment: Thank you- I will try solving this way.

Comment: The problem has changed now: there is an extra 9 in the denominator which I didn't expect: How might I approach the problem now?

Comment: The way you wrote it, you can rewrite $(S^2+1)+9 = S^2 + 10$. If you mean $(S+1)^2 + 9$, you can look at Laplace transforms of functions of the form $e^{at}\cos(bt)$ and $e^{bt}\sin(bt)$.

Comment: Thank you- I'll try this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Alternative Method

$$
F(s)=\underbrace{\frac{s}{(s^2+1)(s^2+9)}}_{\mathbf{(I)}}+\underbrace{\frac{e^{-\pi s}}{s^2+9}}_{\mathbf{(II)}} 
$$

**Alternative (and fast) method for $\mathbf{(I)}$:**

---

We can also decompose $\mathbf{(I)}$ using partial fractions by the following way:

$$
\frac{s}{(s^2+1)(s^2+9)}\equiv\frac{Es+F}{s^2+1}+\frac{Gs+H}{s^2+9}
$$
Finding the constants of partial fractions decomposition
$$
\frac{s}{(s^2+1)(s^2+9)}\equiv\frac{(Es+F)\cdot(s^2+9)+(Gs+H)\cdot(s^2+1)}{(s^2+1)(s^2+9)}
$$

Now, working only with the numerators:
$$s\equiv (E+G)\cdot s^3+(F+H)\cdot s^2+(9E+G)\cdot s+(9F+H)$$
Thus, we can find $E$, $F$, $G$ and $H$ solving the following system of equations:

$$\mbox{$
\begin{cases}
\begin{alignat}{1}
E+G&=0 
\\F+H&=0 
\\9E+G&=1
\\9F+H&=0 
\end{alignat}
\end{cases} 
$}
\implies
\mbox{$
\begin{cases}
\begin{alignat}{1}
E&=1/8 
\\F&=0 
\\G&=-1/8
\\H&=0 
\end{alignat}
\end{cases}
$}
$$

Thus, we get:
$$
\frac{s}{(s^2+1)(s^2+9)}\equiv \frac{s}{8\cdot(s^2+1)}-\frac{s}{8\cdot(s^2+9)}
$$

---

**Now we can apply the Inverse Laplace Transform:**

Remember that the Laplace transform of cosine function is:
$$
\cos(\omega t) \iff \frac{s}{s^2+\omega^2}
$$
So, we have:

$$
\begin{alignat}{1}
\mathscr{L}^{-1}\left[\frac{s}{8\cdot(s^2+1)}-\frac{s}{8\cdot(s^2+9)}\right]&=\frac 1 8 \,\mathscr{L}^{-1}\left[\frac{s}{s^2+1^2}\right]-\frac 1 8 \,\mathscr{L}^{-1}\left[\frac{s}{s^2+3^2}\right]
\\&=\frac{1}{8}\left[cos(t)-cos(3t)\right]
\end{alignat}
$$

---

### Same answer here

$$
\bbox[5px,border:1.1px solid black] {
x(t)=\frac{1}{8}\left[cos(t)-cos(3t)\right]-\frac 1 3\sin(3t)\cdot\operatorname{H}(t-\pi)
}
$$

Answer (score 1):

### Laplace Transform

We have, as pointed in the question, the following equation:
$$x''(t)+ 9x(t) = \cos(t) + \delta(t-\pi)$$
With $x(0)=0$ and $x'(0)=0$. So applying the Laplace Transform:
$$
\require{cancel}
\begin{alignat}{1}
\mathscr{L}\left[x''(t)+9x(t)\right]&=\mathscr{L}\left[ \cos(t) + \delta(t-\pi)\right]
\\ s^2F(s)-s\cancelto{0}{f(0)}-\cancelto{0}{f'(0)}+9F(s)&=\frac{s}{s^2+1^2}+e^{-\pi s}\cdot1
\\s^2F(s)+9F(s)&=\frac{s}{s^2+1}+e^{-\pi s}
\\(s^2+9)\cdot F(s)&=\frac{s+(s^2+1) e^{-\pi s}}{s^2+1}
\end{alignat}$$

So, after the transform, we obtain:
$$ \bbox[5px,border:1.1px solid black] {
F(s)=\frac{s+(s^2+1) e^{-\pi s}}{(s^2+1)(s^2+9)}=\frac{s}{(s^2+1)(s^2+9)}+\frac{e^{-\pi s}}{s^2+9} }
$$

---

Your transform is wrong in two places:
$$F(S) = \frac{S}{(S^2+9)[(S^2+1) \bbox[yellow,4px,border:1.5px solid red]{+9}\,]} + \frac{e^{-\pi\cdot \,  \bbox[yellow,4px,border:1.5px solid red]t}}{S^2+9}$$

---

### Inverse Laplace Transform

Now, we have two parts in the right side to apply the Inverse Laplace Transform:
$$
F(s)=\underbrace{\frac{s}{(s^2+1)(s^2+9)}}_{\mathbf{(I)}}+\underbrace{\frac{e^{-\pi s}}{s^2+9}}_{\mathbf{(II)}} 
$$

**For $\mathbf{(I)}$, we need to decompose it via partial fractions first:**

---

$\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\mathbf{1.}$ Finding zeros of $s^2+1$ and $s^2+9$
$$\begin{alignat}{1}
s^2+1=0 &\iff s=\pm\sqrt{-1}=\pm \,i
\\s^2+9=0 &\iff s=\pm\sqrt{-3}=\pm \,3i
\end{alignat}
$$
Now that we know that $s^2+1=(s+i)\cdot(s-i)$ and $s^2+9=(s+3i)\cdot(s-3i)$, we can proceed the decomposition.

$\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\mathbf{2.}$ Finding the constants of partial fractions decomposition
$$
\frac{s}{(s^2+1)(s^2+9)}\equiv\frac{A}{s+i}+\frac{B}{s-i}+\frac{C}{s+3i}+\frac{D}{s-3i}\equiv
\\\equiv\frac{A\cdot (s-i)(s^2+9)+B\cdot(s+i)(s^2+9)+C\cdot (s^2+1)(s-3i)+D\cdot (s^2+1)(s+3i)}{(s^2+1)(s^2+9)}
$$
Now, working only with the numerators:
$$s\equiv A\cdot (s-i)(s^2+9)+B\cdot(s+i)(s^2+9)+C\cdot (s^2+1)(s-3i)+D\cdot (s^2+1)(s+3i)$$
Since we're dealing with an identity (i.e. valid for every $s$), we can arbitrarily chose values and put them into the identity to find $A$, $B$, $C$ and $D$:

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{alignat}{1}
s=-i &\implies A=\frac{1}{16}
\\ s=i &\implies B=\frac{1}{16}
\\ s=-3i &\implies C=-\frac{1}{16}
\\ s=3i &\implies D=-\frac{1}{16}
\end{alignat}
\end{cases}
$$
Thus, we get:
$$
\frac{s}{(s^2+1)(s^2+9)}\equiv\frac{1/16}{s+i}+\frac{1/16}{s-i}-\frac{1/16}{s+3i}-\frac{1/16}{s-3i}
$$

---

**Now we can apply the Inverse Laplace Transform:**
$$
\mathscr{L}^{-1}\left[\frac{1/16}{s+i}+\frac{1/16}{s-i}-\frac{1/16}{s+3i}-\frac{1/16}{s-3i}\right]=
\\=\frac{1}{16}\,\mathscr{L}^{-1}\left[\frac{1}{s+i}\right]+\frac{1}{16}\,\mathscr{L}^{-1}\left[\frac{1}{s-i}\right]-\frac{1}{16}\,\mathscr{L}^{-1}\left[\frac{1}{s+3i}\right]-\frac{1}{16}\,\mathscr{L}^{-1}\left[\frac{1}{s-3i}\right]
$$
Remembering that the Laplace transform of exponential function is:
$$
e^{-at} \iff \frac{1}{s+a}
$$
We finally have:
$$
\mathscr{L}^{-1}\left[\frac{1/16}{s+i}+\frac{1/16}{s-i}-\frac{1/16}{s+3i}-\frac{1/16}{s-3i}\right]=
\frac{1}{16}e^{-i\cdot t}+\frac{1}{16}e^{i\cdot t}-\frac{1}{16}e^{-3i\cdot t}-\frac{1}{16}e^{3i\cdot t}
$$
Using Euler's identity ($e^{i\cdot\theta}\equiv \cos\theta+i\sin\theta)$, we can write the above result in terms of sines and cosines:
$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{alignat}{1}
e^{-i\cdot t}&=\cos(t)-i\sin(t)
\\e^{i\cdot t}&=\cos(t)+i\sin(t)
\\e^{-3i\cdot t}&=\cos(3t)-i\sin(3t)
\\e^{3i\cdot t}&=\cos(3t)+i\sin(3t)
\end{alignat}
\end{cases} 
\implies \frac{1}{16}\left(e^{-i\cdot t}+e^{i\cdot t}-e^{-3i\cdot t}-e^{3i\cdot t}\right)=\frac{1}{8}\left[cos(t)-cos(3t)\right]
$$

---

**For $\mathbf{(II)}$, we need to use the following:**

$\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\mathbf{1.}$ Laplace time shift property
$$
f(t-a) \cdot \operatorname{H}(t-a) \iff  e^{-a s}\cdot F(s)
$$
(where $\operatorname{H}(t)$ is the Heaviside step function)

$\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\mathbf{2.}$ Laplace transform of sine function
$$
\sin(\omega t) \iff \frac{\omega}{s^2+\omega^2}
$$

Combining these two things, we can find the Inverse Laplace Transform of $\mathbf{(II)}$:

$$
\mathscr{L}^{-1}\left[\frac{e^{-\pi s}}{s^2+9}\right]=\mathscr{L}^{-1}\left[\frac{1} {\color{red}3}\cdot\frac{\color{red}3\cdot e^{-\pi s}}{s^2+3^2}\right]=\frac 1 3 \cdot \mathscr{L}^{-1}\left[e^{-\pi s}\cdot\frac{3}{s^2+3^2}\right]=\frac 1 3\sin(3t-\pi)\cdot\operatorname{H}(t-\pi)
$$

---

### Finally, the answer:

Remembering that $\sin(3t-\pi)=-\sin(3t)$, we have:
$$
\bbox[5px,border:1.1px solid black] {
x(t)=\frac{1}{8}\left[cos(t)-cos(3t)\right]-\frac 1 3\sin(3t)\cdot\operatorname{H}(t-\pi)
}
$$

Comment: The partial fraction decomposition goes easier if you first separate the quadratic factors, treating $s^2$ like a single variable, $$\frac{1}{(s^2+1)(s^2+9)}=\frac{(s^2+9)-(s^2+1)}{8(s^2+1)(s^2+9)}=\frac1{8(s^2+1)}-\frac1{8(s^2+9)}.$$ Such an intermediate decomposition is always possible if the polynomial factors do not have common roots. As one obtains terms that have a direct inverse Laplace transform, no further factorization is necessary.

Comment: @LutzL See my alternative answer below :)

Comment: Brilliant. Everything I needed. Thank you!

Comment: I'm glad it helped :)